# CSRF token mismatch larave-echo-server with nuxt

Tags: laravel, websocket, nuxt.js, laravel-6

i have realtime application in nuxt and laravel with laravel-echo-server

when i use this

```
window.Echo.channel(`laravel_database_test-channel`).listen(
        "TestEvent",
        e => {
          console.log(e);
        }
      );
```

everything works fine

but when i try in private channel like this

```
window.Echo.private(`laravel_database_test-channel`).listen(
        "TestEvent",
        e => {
          console.log(e);
        }
      );
```

getting error `"message": "CSRF token mismatch."`

here is full screenshot

[image: enter code here]

Comment: did you set it up as a private channel on the backend too?

Comment: yes `return new PrivateChannel('test-channel');`

Comment: sounds stupid but you did attach the csrf token to the request, right? also private channels do require the auth middleware to be in place you can't use a private channel without passing auth

Answer (score 4, accepted):

goto App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider modify this

```
Broadcast::routes();
```

to

```
Broadcast::routes(['prefix' => 'api', 'middleware' => ['auth:api']]);
```

and in your `laravel-echo-server.json`

edit this

```
"authEndpoint": "/api/broadcasting/auth",
```

this helps me and working fine

Comment: Thanks, it works! For me , no need prefix and doesnt set the `auth:api` in BroadcastServiceProvider level, but in individual routes/channels.php with `['guards' => ['api']]`